# DNS forwarding using systemd-resolved in a consul cluster setup

Tags: dns, consul

I am exploring consul for service discovery purpose. Following is my consul cluster setup. I am having 3 consul servers & 2 consul clients machines in my cluster on CentOS 7 machine.

consulserver-01 - 192.168.30.112

consulserver-02 - 192.168.30.113

consulserver-03 - 192.168.30.114

consulclient-01 - 192.168.30.115

consulclient-02 - 192.168.30.116

I have successfully registered 3 .NET Core services named service1, service2 and service3 in this cluster which are running on 192.168.30.116 node.Now I want to resolve these services using dns. When i run `dig @192.168.30.112 -p 8600 service1.service.consul SRV` then it successfully resolves it. Now I want to use the `systemd-resolved` service to resolve it automatically. For this I have install `systemd-resolved` package on my consul client i.e. 192.168.30.116 machine and enter the following entries in the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` as

```
DNS=192.168.30.112
Domains=~consul
```

as per the link https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/dns-forwarding. I have also done the following `iptables` entries on my consul client i.e. 192.168.30.116

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.30.112 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8600

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.30.112 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8600
```

Now i expect that when i write `ping service1.service.consul` on 192.168.30.116 it should give me proper IP address i.e. 192.168.30.116.

My response for `dig @192.168.30.112 -p 8600 service1.service.consul SRV` is as follows

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.3 <<>> @192.168.30.112 -p 8600 service1.service.consul SRV
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9837
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;service1.service.consul.       IN      SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
service1.service.consul. 0      IN      SRV     1 1 5555 vmdev0090.node.dc1.consul.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
vmdev0090.node.dc1.consul. 0    IN      A       192.168.30.116
vmdev0090.node.dc1.consul. 0    IN      TXT     "consul-network-segment="

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.30.112#8600(192.168.30.112)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 15 11:22:25 IST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 149
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong or whether my understanding is wrong. Please help in this regard.

Comment: Did you perform a `systemctl restart systemd-resolved` after adding that configuration file? What value are you seeing returned for the DNS query if not 192.168.30.116?

Comment: Yes, I performed ```systemctl restart systemd-resolved```. Output of ```ping service1.service.consul``` is ```ping: service1.service.consul: Name or service not known```.
Also is there a way to do all this without modifying ```iptables```.

Comment: If you are using systemd version 246 or newer you can append the DNS port to the IP in resolved.conf so that it queries Consul directly without needing iptables. For example, `DNS=192.168.30.112:8600`. In order to debug the DNS issue, can you instead share the output of `dig service1.service.consul`? It might be easier to edit your original question and add this information.

Comment: No, I am using ```systemd``` version 219

Comment: I have updated my question with the output of ```dig service1.service.consul```

Comment: The response to the SRV query looks correct. You're querying for `service1.service.consul` and the response is saying that the service is available at 192.168.30.116 on port 5555. Can you run the same `dig` query without explicitly specifying the server IP? iptables should be handling the redirection, assuming the rules are correct. You can verify the rules are being processed by looking at the packet counters from `iptables --table nat --verbose --list OUTPUT`.

Comment: ```dig service1.service.consul

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.3 <<>> service1.service.consul
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 17769
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;service1.service.consul.       IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.30.1#53(192.168.30.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 15 11:51:58 IST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```
It is referring default DNS server i.e. 192.168.30.1

Comment: I figured it out. There is a file named /etc/resolv.conf. In that file there is an entry for nameserver 192.168.30.1, which is my default DNS server. I commented this and added nameserver 192.168.30.112 in this file.
Can it be possible to have both these entries in this file.

Comment: I recommend checking the output of the iptables command that I suggested to verify whether the packets are being appropriately redirected to Consul. If not, check the logs for `systemd-resolved` using `journalctl -u systemd-resolved` to see if it is raising any errors with regard to the configuration.